# How to get related set models without hit database in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-select-related, django-related-manager

Here you'll always get two separate db calls, and adding select_related() anywhere won't help at all. One extra db call isn't that significant.

```
<ul>
{% for obj in myobjects %}
    <li>{{ myobj.name }}</li>
    <ul>
         {% for relobj in myobj.backwardsrelationship_set.all %} {# hit database at every row #}
         <li>{{ relobj.name }}</li>
         {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Any idea here?

Comment: Why `select_related` won't help?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

[prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) can solve this

```
Publisher.objects.filter(city='NY').prefetch_related('book_set')
```